# Java AWT: Drawing Japanese text with Graphics2D.drawString()

Tags: java, awt, drawstring

I'm having issues drawing Japanese text with Graphics2D's drawString() method.  The result is that a series of question marks ("????") is drawn instead of the specified Japanese text.

How can I draw Japanese text onto a BufferedImage with AWT?

Comment: Are you sure the specific `Font` supports Japanese character glyphs?

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: Ahh, it turns out the problem is not with Graphics2D, but with the way I'm retrieving the Japanese input itself.  I'm obtaining it via console input, and upon more testing, it seems that the input is the point at which the text is turning into question marks.

edit: Then again, it may have been with the font after all... I changed many things at once, and something I changed fixed it.  In any case, it's all working now.  Thank you guys.